# Cannot get MobileFirst Access Token on "Specific Scope", just keep getting RegisteredClient Scope

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have been working on Mobile Application using MobileFirst for a while now but I just getting start with push notification until now I am testing out the feature with pushnotifications cordova sample project that available on IBM website. However I able to get push notification to android device via Mobile First Console but When I try to send Push Notification via REST API I have issue

When I request for Access Token from MobileFirst  using Postman I have set Authorization to  `Basic QWRtaW5fTUJGODpQYnVYcjV4SHFtWHo=` which refer to user `test`  that able to access all scope then I set content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded.` For body I set `grant_type` with value `client_credentials` and  `scope` with value `push.application.com.sample.pushnotificationscordova messages.write`

Therefore respond expect to return with scope of push.application.com.sample.pushnotificationscordova messages.write but it not, The response always return `RegisteredClient` like it example below

POST

```
POST /mfp/api/az/v1/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9080
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e3fd2b1e-a709-79eb-5933-257aebfe44f6

grant_type=client_credentials&scope+=messages.write
```

Return Response

`{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp3ayI6eyJrdHkiOiJSd6n06Q...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "RegisteredClient"
}`

In MobileFrist Console I already set scope-Mapping and Scope-Elements Mapping

this mean this token cannot be use to send notification because when use this token to send message it always return

`Bearer error="insufficient_scope", scope="push.application.com.sample.pushnotificationscordova messages.write"`

but I already set  `scope` with value `push.application.com.sample.pushnotificationscordova messages.write` Why the response always return `RegisteredClient`?

Thank you

Comment: RegisteredClient is a default scope that is expected

Comment: Create a new confidential client ( custom ) and add the specific scopes you need. Get an OAuth token using this custom confidential client.

Comment: @VivinK I already try to create new Confidential Client for specific scopes (You can look at screenshot https://ibb.co/GpmGPTx)  but still returning "RegisteredClient"

Comment: You are getting only RegisteredClient? Or that is one among many scopes?

Comment: @VivinK Yes only get RegisteredClient I don't know why. I try on both Develop and production server turn out the same way

Comment: Open a case with IBM for further analysis of logs and your configuration.